# I get 'Indirect modification of overloaded property ...' after I deployed cakephp app to my host

Tags: php, cakephp

I upload my PHPCake  to my hosting website but I started getting Indirect modification of overloaded property AppModel::$MyModel has no effect

In this model I have association to another model so when I try to accesses via

```
$this->MyModel->OtherModel->id = $id;
```

I get the error. 
It's working on my computer but it dosen't work on the website. Not sure if the website php configuration dosen't support it.

Comment: if you got an AppModel there, your model relations seem to be wrong in your model relation setup. PS: why is there is space between `-> in`?

Comment: Space before and after `->` is ignored in PHP.

Comment: Still doesn't belong there.. Is this your real setup? or did you make the names "MyModel" and "OtherModel" up? You should not do so as this abstraction potentially hides your real mistakes.

Comment: @MujtabaAlboori, I don't know the answer, but as far as debugging: do you have different versions of PHP or different error reporting levels locally versus on the server? And what kind of warning is it: WARNING, NOTICE, STRICT?

Comment: Permissions issue? We have to assume everything you are working with in a test environment is identical to your deployed site unless you have more details for us.

Comment: It's working in the test environment but when I upload it to the website I get this error:  'Indirect modification of overloaded property AppModel::$Cat6 has no effect [APP/Controller/Cat6ItemsController.php, line 25]'

Comment: I tried to re-upload the same files in the test environment still the same problem.

Comment: if it's Permissions issue how can I fix it ?

Comment: is that supposed to be `$id`? not `id`

Comment: @TimJoyce it's $id. The code above is not what I have. I'm just trying to simplify here but the problem dosen't with id. It's that CakePhp dosen't recognise the association link between the models.

Comment: @TheCapn I realize myModel is not detected. I remove the model file and the controller is working and dosen't complain about the model dosen't exist .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. It turned out the problem with model file name. It's sensitive to capitals letters in the website but it dosen't seem to mind it in the computer. BTW, I'm using Mac OSX as test environment with MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->MyModel->OtherModel-> id = id;
```

is missing the $ before id.

Double-check your model relationships. 'OtherModel' must be associated with 'MyModel'.

Comment: Why it's working on my computer but when I upload it to the website it dosen't work. I double-checked the Model, and it has no problem. And Model looks like this in MyModel
 var $name = 'MyModel';
 var $hasMany = 'OtherModel';